# How to query Google spreadsheet cell for date before 2016-02-16

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a Google spreadsheet containing subscriptions. I need to query that spreadsheet to find out what subscriptions have expired. By searching on the internet, I've found I can query the spreadsheet to find out which subscribers expire *after* a certain date (2016-02-16 in this example) with this command:

```
=QUERY(Everyone!$A:$ZZ, "SELECT * WHERE H >= date '2016-02-16' ORDER BY H",-1)
```

(The expiration date is in column H.)

If the date in question is in a certain cell (E2 in this example) I can do that here too:

```
=QUERY(Everyone!$A:$ZZ, "SELECT * WHERE H >= date '" & text(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ORDER BY H",-1)
```

I want to know the subscribers that have an expiration date *before* 2016-02-16. I thought I could just replace the `>=` with `<`, but that returns no results. (I know I have dates before 2016.)

So my question:

**How to query in a Google spreadsheet to find all dates *less than* a specified date?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of your sheet you will see your data. The issue is with Order By. The null cells in H are sorted first. Add AND H IS NOT NULL and it should solve this.

```
=QUERY(Everyone!A:J, "SELECT * WHERE H < date '2016-02-16' AND H IS NOT NULL ORDER BY H",-1)
```

Another option would be to have the exact row numbers Everyone!A1:J16. Then blank cells are not an issue.

Comment: I wish you were correct. My table is quite small (for now); it only goes up to column `J`. If I change `ZZ` to `J`, I still can't use `<`. I don't get a `#REF!` error, the query only returns the first line of the table in `Everyone` (which is the headers).

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Do you know why it is needed to ensure that `H IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: If you do not ensure that H is not null and you specify your data range without row numbers (i.e. A:J) column H includes all cells to the end of the sheet. those null (blank cells will sort first so you data was there when you do not exclude the nulls, they were just down at the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make use of a filter? You can do that such as

`=filter(Everyone!$A:$ZZ, H4:H>H3)`

//Where H3 is where you put the date of your choice.